# Dynamically set value of input box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx page with an input textbox control for which i want to set a value. I want it so that the value dynamically changes based on the current text of the textbox when the form is submitted. Does anyone know how to do this without jquery?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Changes how? What is the desired value?

Comment: So just to clarify, user submits form -> the value of the textbox changes based on what the text is at time of submit? How does it change?

Comment: Its really difficult to understand what you truing to achieve here. Could you edit your question in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for, not sure though:

**JavaScript:**

```
function ChangeValue(currentTxtBox, newValue)
{
     var otherTxtbox = document.getElementById('<%=otherTxtbox.ClientID%>');
     otherTxtbox.value = currentTxtBox.value;
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<asp:textbox id="bla" runat="server" onchange="ChangeValue(this)" />

<asp:textbox id="otherTxtbox " runat="server" />
```